# jQuery can't parse value from a item which has ID with special char '*'

Tags: c#, jquery, urlencode

It seems that jQuery can't parse value from a item which has ID with special char '*'.
The below statement is not returning anything if the jobID has special char '*' i.e. item123*1

```
      var itemValue  = $(jobID).val();
```

As C# in backend in my MVC web app, so I tried to encode using HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode() before sending data to view.
But UrlEncode() is not encoding special char '*'.

Anybody faced the same type of issue before?

Comment: * is not a valid character for a html element id. You'll need to replace it with something else such as an underscore.

Comment: @user1751825 You ought to literally post that as an answer because that's all that there is to it. Wait a second, it is valid HTML. I've never used it as an id, but technically it's valid.

Comment: Some context might help.  How about trying a console.log(jobID); ?

Answer (score 1):

IDs with an asterisk (`*`) are accepted in HTML5, but the asterisk is used as a metacharacter in CSS selector strings. You need to escape metacharacters using two backslashes (`\\`).

See [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more information.

```js
console.log($("#item123\\*1").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="item123*1" value="test">
```